# $p = (u + v)^2 + uv$ for primes $p = 5k \pm 1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I came up with the following conjecture which I am unable to prove.

For all primes $p$ which can be represented as either $5k + 1$ or $5k - 1$ for some positive integer $k$, we can find positive integers $u$, $v$ such that

$p = (u + v)^2 + u \times v$

For example,
$31 = 5 \times 6 + 1 = (2 + 3)^2 + 2 \times 3$

Using a computer, I have verified it for $p < 10000$.
Is there a general proof for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'd like to use some algebraic number theory (Kummer-Dedekind) to prove this, and in order to do that, we need to link $(u+v)^2+uv$ to the norm of some quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. This must be possible, because $(u+v)^2+uv$ is homogeneous of degree $2$. Let $\varphi:=\frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ be the golden ratio, then:
$$
\begin{align*}
(u+v)^2+uv&=0\\
(u/v)^2+3(u/v)+1&=0\\
u/v&=\frac12(-3\pm\sqrt{5})\\
u/v&\in\{\varphi-2,-\varphi-1\}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now we find that
$$
\begin{align*}
u^2+v^2+3uv &=  (u-(\varphi-2)v)(u+(\varphi+1)v)\\
&=\left((u+2v)-\varphi v\right)\left((u+2v)-\bar{\varphi}v\right)\\
&= N_{\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)/\mathbb{Q}}\left((u+2v)-\varphi v\right).
\end{align*}
$$

---

So if $p$ is a prime number, then $p$ can be written as $(u+v)^2+uv$ if and only if $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ contains elements of norm $p$, which is to say that $(p)$ splits in $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ as a product of principal ideals. By Kummer-Dedekind and the fact that the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ is $1$, this is equivalent to $X^2-X-1$ splitting over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Note that $X^2-X-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$. For all odd primes $p$, its roots are given by $\frac12(1\pm\sqrt 5)$, so it splits as the product of two distinct linear factors if and only if $\left(\frac5p\right)=1$. Quadratic reciprocity gives that
$$
\left(\frac 5p\right)=\left(\frac p5\right)=\begin{cases}0\quad&\text{if $p=5$}\\1&\text{if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod {5}$}\\-1&\text{if $p\equiv \pm 2\pmod 5$},\end{cases}
$$
so we can write $p=N_{\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)/\mathbb{Q}}(s+\varphi t)$ for integers $s,t$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod 5$ or $p=5$.

Comment: Thank you. I admit I don't have the background knowledge necessary to understand the proof, so I will accept it if enough people think it is correct.

Comment: @MathsLion1234 Fair enough. It shouldn't be that hard to understand the part above the line (the primes we are looking for are exactly the primes $p$ we can write as $p=(s+\varphi t)(s+\bar{\varphi}t)$ where $s,t$ are integers, $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$ and $\bar{\varphi}=\frac12(1-\sqrt 5)$) Once you understand that, this question is essentially about how primes factor in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$.

Comment: This method is fairly common -- if you want to look at an easier problem where the same method is used, look at the proof that the only odd primes which can be written as the sum of two squares are the primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $p=(x+y)^2+xy = x^2+y^2+3xy=(x-y)^2+5xy$

If $q$ is an integer not divisible by $5$, then $q^2 \equiv 1$ mod $5$. As $p \neq 5$ is prime, it cannot be divided by $5$ and since $x-y$ not divisible by $5$, hence it follows $p \equiv \, 1$ mod $5$. Now, this runs only one way, the converse it not necessarily true from my statement, that for some $p \equiv 1$ mod $5$, then $p=x^2+y^2+2xy$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand it. What is q? For some q not divisible by 5, q^2 being 4 mod 5 is also possible. Edit: Are you trying to show that p = (u + v)^2 + uv implies p is 1, 4 mod 5?

Comment: @MathsLion1234 Hello, yes the latter part of your comment is what I am showing here.